# Is Caching Via Database Inefficient For Production Sites?

Tags: php, mysql, database, caching

I need to move a bunch of background processes for a production website onto another server, to help spread out the CPU and RAM usage. One obstacle I have is that a few of these background processes generate (and store in a file-based cache) HTML views and other data which the site front-end relies upon. So, I will need to switch to a more centralized caching system so that my servers can share the cached data.

I am considering just using the (MySQL) database for this however I am concerned that this will dramatically increase the DB hits. Is this efficient? What are some alternatives?

Comment: try reading more about memcached, works for me.

Comment: memcache, redis, even APCu for alternative caches; you could also look at varnish in front of your webserver; or edge-side includes if your framework supports it

Comment: will memcached work across multiple servers?

Comment: @phirschybar - memcache can run on the same server, a different server entirely, or even on several other servers; as can redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move this to a distributed task queue implementation, like [gearman](http://gearman.org/) for async tasks, and [memcached](http://memcached.org/) for your caching and other transient data needs.